# For 0<a/b< 1 and 0<c/d, prove that a/b * c/d < c/d

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

I've done (0 < a/b < 1) * c/d 
          = 0 < ac/bd < c/d
Not sure if this is right or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is correct only if $\frac{c}{d}>0$. In this case, we have:
$$0<\frac{a}{b}<1 \leftrightarrow 0\cdot\frac{c}{d}<\frac{a}{b}\cdot\frac{c}{d}<\frac{c}{d}$$
by the proprieties of inequalities. So, you are right $\color{red}{\text{only if} \;\frac{c}{d}>0}$

Comment: so my answer is correct, right?

Comment: Yes, it is but see my edits.